# Converting binary value to string and back to binary?

Tags: coldfusion, binary, decode, encode, rowversion

I have `rowversion` value that comes from Database in binary format. I need to convert that value to string in order to pass in my front-end code. Then when user submits data back to the server I need to convert that string back to binary. Here is example of my data:

```
Binary 00000010586
```

Above output is what I see when my query result returns value. Then I tried this:

Encoded value looks like this: `iV`

Then I tried to decode value back and this is what I have used:

```
#charsetDecode( local.encodedVal, "utf-8" )#
```

Then I got this error message: `ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings.`

In my database row version column has `timestamp` type. When query returns that value it's represented as binary in ColdFusion. I use this column as unique id for each row set in my table. Is there a way to handle this conversion in CldFusion adn what would be the best approach?

Comment: Add 4 space to your first code block so that it'll display.

Comment: Arrgggh...  didn't notice you'd already asked about the binary issue here too ;-) Just finished writing up how to handle that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52040916/update-record-based-on-rowversion-value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your working with binary data, and not with string encodings. You will need to use [`binaryEncoded`](https://cfdocs.org/binaryencode) and [`binaryDecode`](https://cfdocs.org/binarydecode) to send your data as a string and convert it back to binary.

The following example converts some binary data into 2 string representations and converts them back into the same byte array with `binaryDecode`in the dump.

```
<cfscript>
    binaryData = toBinary("SomeBinaryData++");
    hexEncoded = binaryEncode(binaryData, "hex");
    base64Encoded = binaryEncode(binaryData, "base64");

    writeDump([
        binaryData,
        hexEncoded,
        base64Encoded,
        binaryDecode(hexEncoded, "hex"),
        binaryDecode(base64Encoded, "base64")
    ]);
</cfscript>
```

Run the example on [TryCF.com](https://trycf.com/gist/7cafb826924e5eef976eb4185eb113ad/acf2018?theme=monokai)